# C# and Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying to learn C# from some YouTube videos, but I have a few concerns. I started with JavaScript, wanted to learn a software language, so I learned some C++, but then I found out that C# is better for GUI programming, so now I'm going with that.

The problem is that I feel like VS is doing a lot of things I should know how to do but don't... When I add a button or create a new class or something it's all done with VS. I want to know what it's doing, though, so I can do it myself if I need to.

I'm on the video explaining classes, and I was wondering where the header file was. I couldn't find it, so I searched online and, come to find out, unlike C++, C# doesn't have header files. Are the class files automatically linked?

Is it practical to learn how to do everything manually, or is C# done solely in VS anyway? Is there a way to keep track of what files and code snippets are added and created when a button is pressed in VS?

Comment: It is useful to understand what's happening under the hood, but it's not essential. As an IDE, it automates these tasks for you as they'll otherwise be really tedious or mundane, so you can focus on writing actual application logic and also to prevent a number of bugs.

Comment: The code for the GUI is usually added to `YourFormName.designer.cs`, where YourFormName is the name of your form. You can also right click on any method and click `GoToDefinition` to go to the implementation

Comment: I think you should try to read any book instead of looking at video. If you really want to use C# later.. Something like http://www.apress.com/microsoft/c/9781430225379

Comment: Yes it is good to know how those things work, but starting with C# and not worrying about that means you can focus on improving you're understanding of programming. You can always go back and learn objective C if you feel that you are lacking knowledge in that area.

Comment: It seems like with VS there is always a place to view the source code of what it is 'automatically' doing for you. Sure it is beneficial to understand all of what is going on but one thing I like about VS is that it takes care of what I call the fine print so you can get stuff done faster. For me I don't think I will ever do any C# programming outside of VS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am bias, but the best way to understand and learn what is going on in a program is to debug it.

Creating a new C# app in Visual Studio will give you the fastest path to this. You shouldn't have to worry too much what Visual Studio is generating for you, because if you want to understand it, simply step through the code in the debugger. You can see exactly what calls are being made, how each of them changes state, etc, etc.

If you make a basic GUI app, then step through the InitializeComponents function, that gives you a really good sense of how VS sets things up for you.

C# can be used outside of VS, but having all the components so you can just hit F10 and starting stepping away in the IDE makes it the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

Well, best way would be to not use the VS Designer, if you want to learn what happens behind the curtains. You may of course code every single line by hand and it still will work. Eg. to add a button:

```
Form form = new Form();  // create my form
Button button = new Button(); // create the button
button.Text = "Click me!"; // add some text
form.Controls.Add(button); // add the button to the form
Application.Run(form);  // start the applications main thread and display the button
```

There are dozens of tutorials outside, just find the one that suits you best.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that visual studio is giving you all the preregistered stuff in built. So you just need to build your own class templates the definition will be presented to you default.

So if you create a class call employee it will create basic syntax for you and you need to write the logic directly.

Thanks,
Jigar

Answer (score 0):

C# as a language is used to develop several kinds of applications such as console-based applications, Windows desktop applications and Web applications.

For the former, you will code everything mostly by hand, even if you are using Visual Studio.

For the latter two, since they are GUI based, it's recommended to use Visual Studio so that you can use the drag-and-drop approach as well as have Visual Studio take care of the routine tasks so that you can focus on the logic and actual development.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, you shouldn't try to learn everythin, but anyway - core concepts will broaden your understanding and will surely help you in further dev-life.

If you want what exactly VS do with your code - put some "VCS guard" at top of project. Use Git or Mercurial and you could see exact changes that was applied to each file (commit everything before you going perform interesting action and check changes after). It could help you to track anything that will happens with your project. But for most cases its not very  productive to do everything by hands. DevTools were made to remove very bored routine.

Its very useful to know how you can do something without VS installed, but all such tasks is usually not directly related to programming, mainly its some kind of supporting stuff.
Ex. how build a project with msbuild or csc.exe (C# compiler) to setup homebrew continuous integration system.

If you want really deep grasp into .NET - read CLR via C# by Jeffrey Richter. IMO it's far more important to know system guts than to know how to place button on the form without VS-designer.